# variable assignment to input value

Tags: javascript, php

i have this .js code:

```
var test = document.getElementById('box').innerHTML;
```

and this html code

```
<textarea id="box">testing</textarea>
<div>
     <?php echo '<script>document.writeln(test)</script>' ?>
</div>
```

i was expecting the `div`'s would show `testing` but, instead, i got `undefined` result. but then, when i change the `var test` to:

```
var test = "this is just a test";
```

the `div` shows exactly the `var test` value. can someone explain what happens there?

Comment: Open your Javascript console, do you see an error message?

Comment: Based on what you've shown us, you're attempting to load the `innerHTML` before the element has been loaded. As Barmar mentioned, you should see an error in your console.

Comment: @Barmar yes, i did get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`. i tried to find solution but couldn't get one. i'm kinda new in php

Comment: What does that have to do with PHP? It's a Javascript error. It should be obvious that `getElementById('box')` is returning `null`.

Comment: @HSK2609 That's a JavaScript error, not a PHP one. It means that `document.getElementById('box')` returned `null` which happens when it can't find an element with that ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
var test = document.getElementById('box').innerHTML;
```

is being ran after your page is loading, and therefore, test is NOT defined. The other script is running first, because it is found first.

If you REALLY want to do it, you can do something like this. Put the script that defines test immediately after the HTML element you are targeting. That will define the variable `test`.

```html
<textarea id="box">testing</textarea>
<script>var test = document.getElementById('box').innerHTML;</script>
<div>
     <script>document.writeln(test)</script>
</div>
```